# Cloud9 PHP error log file

Tags: php, cloud9-ide, error-log

I swear I saw a error log in the Terminal of C9. I just can't find the path and the file anymore.

Any tips or ideas where / how to find?

To some paths/files I don't have permission with the standard user that is "ubuntu". As I read it isn't possible to use sudo, is it? For example I assumed to find the log at /var/log/apache2 but permission is denied.

Answer (score 3):

Currently mine is at

```
/home/ubuntu/lib/apache2/log/error.log
```

I discovered this by looking at the terminal/console that opens up below the editor when you start Apache.

Comment: This log is not current.  This log is not helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a php.ini copy overhere:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c9/templates/master/ws-php/files/home/workspace/php.ini

Part of the [Cloud 9 Template repository](https://github.com/c9/templates/).

Make the changes...

And copy it in your workspace folder.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found out following solution on [this site](http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/23272371-PHP-sessions):

- download an adjusted php.ini file from the link
- place it in your workspace folder
- start apache again

You'll have an error log file named php_errors.log in the same directory (workspace)